# What would cause a zip file to not be recognized on Google App Engine's when it reads properly in my local GAE sdk

Tags: python, google-app-engine, zip

My code executes successfully when I run it locally, but when I upload it to GAE and attempt to run it throws me a BadZipfile: File is not a zip file, or ends with a comment

```
raw_file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
buffer = cStringIO.StringIO(raw_file.read())
z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
```

zipped file size is 2.5 mb
unzipped size is 14 mb

What is the difference in the two environments that is causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size you can fetch using urlfetch (App Engine's API for making HTTP requests to other sites) is 1MB, so your file is getting truncated. The dev_appserver doesn't enforce the 1MB limit.

Comment: Is there anyway to request files larger than 1MB from App Engine?

Comment: Not currently, no, unless you use multiple range requests and concatenate them together.